# MySQL Multiple LIKE between multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I had search for the solution but so far i didn't find it yet.

So here the problem, let say i have 2 table:

Table1

```
name | code
-------------------
a    | [a][b][c]
b    | [a][c][d]
c    | [a][e]
```

Table2

```
code | name
-------------------
a    | aaaa
b    | bbbb
c    | cccc
d    | dddd
e    | eeee
```

I want to do multiple select `Table1.name` and `Table2.name` where `Table1.code LIKE '%b%'` OR `Table1.code LIKE '%e%'`

so it should be result like this:

```
name | name
------------------
a    | aaaa
c    | cccc
```

I did try :

```
SELECT Table1.name, Table2.name 
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE Table1.code LIKE '%b%' OR Table1.code LIKE '%e%'
```

But it didn't work. I'm newbie on this, any help deeply appreciated :)

Comment: What is thte connection between the 2 tables ?

Comment: table1.code is foreign key of table2.code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder to join 2 table using **like**  function or **instr** function will

Using **"like"**

```
 **column_name1 like '%'column_name2'%'**
```

Using **"instr"**

```
 **instr(column_name1,column_name2)>0**
```

where **column_name1  is referencing column**  and **column_name2 is pattern you are searching**

in your example try this

**Using like**

```
SELECT Table1_name, Table2_name FROM 
( SELECT Table1.name table1_name
        ,Table1.code table1_code
        ,Table2.name table2_name
        ,Table2.code table2_code
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON  
(Table2.name LIKE '%'||Table1.name||'%') OR (Table1.code LIKE '%'||Table2.code||'%')
WHERE Table1.name=Table2.code
)  new1
 WHERE Table1_code LIKE '%b%' OR Table1_code LIKE '%e%'
```

**Using INSTR**

```
 SELECT Table1_name, Table2_name FROM 
( SELECT Table1.name table1_name
        ,Table1.code table1_code
        ,Table2.name table2_name
        ,Table2.code table2_code
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON
INSTR(Table2.name,Table1.name)>0   OR INSTR(Table1.code,Table2.code)>0 
WHERE Table1.name=Table2.code
)  new1
 WHERE Table1_code LIKE '%b%' OR Table1_code LIKE '%e%'
```

Comment: WOW, your code really made my day, it's work like i want. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name FROM 
Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.name = t2.code)
WHERE t1.code LIKE '%b%' OR t1.code LIKE '%e%'
```

Since this is an inner join this will only return rows from the first table if there is a matching code in the second. If you would want to display any matching rows from Table1 use LEFT JOIN

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i use your code above, then it return zero result, when i change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, it show NULL in the t2.name .. hmm .. or maybe t1.code must be exacly same with t2.code ??

Comment: No, i use your example above with my data (different table name, field, etc), i think it didn't work because Table1.code value not exactly same with Table2.code. 

btw thanks for the answer, it give me enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AND table2 WHERE table1code LIKE '%e%'
```